# What latex package would you recommend for drawing simple diagrams of the following sort?

Tags: graphics, packages, diagrams

My goal is to find a latex package to convert data I have in ASCII form,
looking like

```
                    >----+----+---->
                         |    |.33
                    >----|----o---->
                         |.50 |.33
                    >----+----+---->
```

and

```
+=====================================+
|9  6  3.133                          |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1 >-+-----------+-----+------->  x  |
| 2 >-|--+--------|--+--+-----+->  x  |
| 3 >-|--|--+-----+--|-----+--+->  x  |
| 4 >-|--|--|--+-----+-----+---->  x  |
| 5 >-+--+--+--+---------------->  x  |
+=====================================+
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  .50 .33 .25 .20 .33 .42 .40 .40 .30
```

to something professional looking (nice clean horizontal lines, vertical line segments etc).

Basically, there are horizontal lines (can be more than 5), some vertical line segment, some markers (bullets, x, etc) and some numbers to be placed.

I am aware of `pstricks` and TikZ but I hope for something simple especially as my data has the form as shown above.

Thanks.

Comment: Since there is something left to the imagination, could you edit your question to include an actual image (uploaded or web-based) that shows *exactly* what the appearance format should be

Comment: Without using any particular package, LaTeX `tabular` environment can create tables with horizontal and vertical lines between the cells. Fancier results can be obtained with a few simple packages. Have a look at the Wikibooks page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for your question. I don't know yet how it should look like but it is part of a paper and journals these days would frown on a ASCII graphics.

Comment: I was thinking a non-ASCII version already existed on paper and you just were using ASCII in an attempt to render it for our benefit.  But, if I understand, you are the formulator of this ASCII style and would like to pretty it up.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes correct, my job is to *prettify* the ASCII code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend tikz: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ

Or some package based on tikz for some special case, for example I've used some special packages for genealogy trees and for logic gates NANDs NORs and so on ;) I think there is some tikz/latex package for most use-cases.